# Oracle Endeca two way thesaurus not showing same number of records

Tags: endeca

I have defined two way thesaurus for few entries in the pipeline. Two way thesaurus is expected to give same number of results when searched for any of the entries specified in the two way thesaurus. But its not working so. For Example, there are two entries like fresh veg and fresh vegetable defined as two way thesaurus. When searched for fresh veg in jspref, its providing 0 or 10 records. But when searched for fresh vegetables its showing hundreds of records. Match mode is all. Why is this working in a weird manner. And how to trouble shot/ solve this issue.

Comment: Endeca version? Also was the thesaurus configured through Experience Manager or the pipeline's xml file?

Comment: Endeca version : 11.1.0

Comment: thesaures added in pipeline's xml

Comment: Do you use experience manager? if yes have you tried to configure the same entry there?

Comment: No, I am just using Endeca search

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description you have a thesaurus entry as follow:

```
Fresh Vegetable <==> Fresh Veg
```

This, according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37502_01/server.751/es_dev/src/cdg_stemming_troubleshooting_thesaurus.html), is incorrect and can lead to incorrect values.

> Avoid multi-word thesaurus forms where single-word forms are appropriate. In particular, avoid multi-word forms that are not phrases that users are likely to type, or to which phrase expansion is likely to provide relevant additional results.
>
> For example, the two-way thesaurus entry:
>   Aethelstan, King Of England (D. 939) = Athelstan, King Of England (D. 939)
>   should be replaced with the single-word form:
>
> Aethelstan = Athelstan

This suggests that you will get the correct two-way result if you simply map:

```
Vegetable <==> Veg
```

Comment: Hi Radimpe, Thanks for the help. In my case, when ever the user searches for any item and ended up with 0 results, those words are noted and configured as thesaurus entries.

Comment: For Ex, balsamic vin and balsamic vinaigrette. Configured this example as two way thesaurus. balsamic vin is giving me 146 records and balsamic vinaigrette is showing 967 records. Why there is difference in number of records. What changes to be done in order get correct number of results

Comment: and one more example, pineapple is giving me 6137 records where as pine apple is giving me 0 records. It was working fine and gave me exact number of records earlier.

Comment: thanks radimpe for your help. I was able to solve with your inputs